# How can I compact this code with a Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have this code for checking if the all the descendant nodes of a node are expanded or not.
How can I compact this code with a Linq expression? I understand how the code works but I'm not being able to do the same thing in Linq.

```
    public bool AllChildRowsExpanded()
    {
        if (!this.IsExpanded)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var row in this.ContainedRows)
        {
            if (row.ContainedRows == null || row.ContainedRows.Count == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (!row.AllChildRowsExpanded())
            {
                return false;
            }                    
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Im just curious as to what kind of compact result you're expecting to achieve using linq? Could you perhaps clarify what kind of result you're expecting to end up with? Is it a oneliner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense it further down using just one expression bodied method.

```
public bool AllChildRowsExpanded()
    => IsExpanded && (ContainedRows == null || ContainedRows.All(r => r.AllChildRowsExpanded()));
```

Comment: `AllChildRowsAreExpanded` -> `AllChildRowsExpanded`? Also, missing `;`.